# Why can't the code find this method from another class?

Tags: class, methods, boolean

I am trying to check that the input number is within a required range by referencing the method weightReasonable(double aWeight) from another class. At the moment I am getting these two errors:

WaterTankProg.java:55: error: double cannot be dereferenced
          if (weight.weightReasonable)
                    ^
WaterTankProg.java:55: error: illegal start of type
          if (weight.weightReasonable)
             ^

This is the input method in one class:

```
   public static double inputTankWeight ()
    { 
        double weight = 0;
        boolean inputSuccessful = false;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!inputSuccessful)
        {
        System.out.print("Enter weight of the tank in kilograms when empty: ");  
        try 
        {
          weight = scan.nextDouble();
          if (weight.weightReasonable)
          inputSuccessful = true;
        }
      catch (InputMismatchException e)
      {
      scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You didn't enter a recognisable number.");
      }
        }
        return weight;
    }
```

This is the check method in another class:

```
public boolean weightReasonable(double aWeight)
    {
        return (aWeight > 0.0 && aWeight <= MAX_WEIGHT);
    }
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `if (weightReasonable(weight))`?

Comment: In which class is weightReasonable defined? You are calling weightReasonable from an "object" of type double. And double doesn't have that method.

Comment: weightReasonable is defined in a class called WaterTank whilst the inputTankWeight is in WaterTankProg. I did try weightReasonable(weight) and got the error message "WaterTankProg.java:54: error: cannot find symbol if (weightReasonable(weight)) ^ symbol: method weightReasonable(double) location: class WaterTankProg"

Comment: You should learn the basics of OOP first. You have to create a new instance with something like `WaterTank waterTank = new WaterTank();` to be able to call it using `waterTank.weightReasonable(weight)`. Or you define your method weightReasonable as static. Then you could call it using `WaterTank.weightReasonable(weight)` without creating a new instance first.